# Cant call instance methods from other classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I hope you can help me with the following problem in Objective-C. I´ve been sitting around for two hours now, but I have no idea what´s wrong.

Here´s my code:

BMICalc.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BMICalc : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *bmiArray;

-(int)bmiRows;

@end
```

BMICalc.m:

```
#import "BMICalc.h"

@implementation BMICalc

@synthesize bmiArray;

- (int) bmiRows
{
    if (!bmiArray)
    {
      bmiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return [bmiArray count];
}

@end
```

Now I want to create a object of BMICalc in another class called BMIDiaryController:

BMIDiaryController.m:

```
#import "BMIDiaryController.h"
#import "BMICalc.h"

@interface BMIDiaryController ()

@end

@implementation BMIDiaryController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BMICalc *bmiSender = [[BMICalc alloc] init];

    int bmiVariable = [bmiSender bmiRows];       
}

@end
```

So when I start the programme i get the following error:
"No visible @interface for 'BMICalc' declares the selector 'bmiRows'

I can´t call the method "bmiRows" with the object "bmiSender" (both of Class "BMICalc"

I hope you can help me with this. I searched and searched...I think it´s just a small thing, but I won´t see it...

Thank you and regards,

Stefan

Comment: It says `BMIClass` in your error message, but it's `BMICalc` in your program. Did you type the name incorrectly?

Comment: Does the error really say BMIClass, not BMICalc, or is that a typo?

Comment: Oh, I´m sorry, of course it´s "BMICalc"

Comment: Did you try a clean and then build or analyze?

Comment: Yes, i tried a clean, a build and a analyze. Nothing happened :-(

Comment: Were the BMICalc files added to the project so that they are being built as part of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new project.  Then add the BMICalc.m and BMICalc.h files.  Try to instantiate your BMICalc object and call the bmiRows method from the appDelegate just to test it.  There could be any number of things wrong in your main project that may be interfering with the class.  At least doing this will confirm that you aren't crazy and that this code isn't the problem :)

Comment: I just created a new project and added BMICalc.m and BMICalc.h - it worked! Crazy... I´ll try to recreate my whole project, this should work. Weired. Thank you very much!